# Correct Use of Typeclasses in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I wrote a typeclass to avoid having to write a duplicate function for a different type as below:

```
import Statistics.Distribution.Normal
import Data.Random

d1 :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
d1 s k r v t = ( log ( s / k ) + ( ( v * v ) / 2 ) * t ) / ( v * sqrt t )

d2 :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
d2 s k r v t = d1 s k r v t - v * sqrt t

call :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
call s k r t v = exp ( -r * t ) * ( s * cdf normal ( d1 s k r v t )
                                  - k * cdf normal ( d2 s k r v t ) )
  where normal = Normal (0 :: Double) 1

put :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
put s k r t v = exp ( -r * t ) * ( k * cdf normal ( - d2 s k r v t )
                                 - s * cdf normal ( - d1 s k r v t ) )
  where normal = Normal (0 :: Double) 1

class Black a where
  price :: a -> Double -> Double -> Double

instance Black ( Option Future ) where
  price ( Option ( Future s ) Call European k t ) r v = call s k r t v
  price ( Option ( Future s ) Put European k t ) r v = put s k r t v

instance Black ( Option Forward ) where
  price ( Option ( Forward s ) Call European k t ) r v = call s k r t v
  price ( Option ( Forward s ) Put European k t ) r v = put s k r t v
```

Is this a valid use of typeclasses? The reason I am asking is that I am not overloading the definition of the price function for any given type. All I am doing is avoiding having to write:

```
priceFuture :: (Option Future) -> Double -> Double -> Double
// impl
priceFoward :: (Option Forward) -> Double -> Double -> Double
impl



data Option a = Option a Type Style Strike Expiration deriving (Show)
data Future = Future Price deriving (Show)
data Forward = Forward Price deriving (Show)

type Barrier = Double
type Expiration = Double
type Price = Double
type Strike = Double
type Value = Double
type Dividend = Double
type Rate = Double

data Type = Call | Put deriving (Eq, Show)
data Style = European | American deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Comment: Where's the definition of `Option` and `Forward`/`Future`?

Comment: @Zeta, I've added the types.

Comment: @Why are those three types? Why not `data OptionKind = Future | Forward`? By the way, now `Price` is missing. And `Type`. And `Style`.

Comment: @Zeta, added the other types.

Answer (score 5):

I think I would just make the the argument to `Option` be a phantom type:

```
data Option a = Option Price Type Style Strike
data Future
data Forward

price :: Option a -> Double -> Double -> Double
price (Option s Call European k t) r v = call s k r t v
price (Option s Put  European k t) r v = put  s k r t v
```

Much less repetition, and no need for a type-class, but you still get a type-level distinction between forward options (`Option Forward`) and future options (`Option Future`) should you need that elsewhere. If you're really excited, you could turn on `DataKinds` to make sure that `Future` and `Forward` are the only two possible type-level arguments to `Option`.

Comment: I have about 7 other different types like future and forward that I have to code for as well. Those types will have other attributes so sticking them all in the Option type as above would not be a good idea I think. The fields I have for Option at the moment (from a business perspective) pertain to that type only and not to Forward, Future and the other types I have. I tried to separate them out as I have done into their own types so the information does not get conflated. This is my first foray with Haskell and in particular Haskell design.

Comment: Also I'm just wondering what was stopping me from pattern matching like you have done above when I have an Option type which is higher kinded. To me, it made sense to make Option a type constructor because in itself it is useless until another type is added to it to make it into a financial contract. I was just making that notion explicit.

Comment: @Mika'il In such a case, a typeclass might be okay. But I would suggest a much smaller class; perhaps `class HasPrice a where getPrice :: a -> Price` with instances for `Forward` and `Future`; then write something like `optionPrice :: HasPrice a => Option a -> Double -> Double -> Double; optionPrice (Option s Call European k t) r v = call (getPrice s) k r t v`.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I was thinking on similar lines as well but never went forward that idea. I will investigate it.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
data Option = Option ForFut Type Style Strike Expiration deriving (Show)
data ForFut = Forward Price | Future Price deriving (Show)

type Barrier = Double
type Expiration = Double
type Price = Double
type Strike = Double
type Value = Double
type Dividend = Double

type Rate = Double

data Type = Call | Put deriving (Eq, Show)
data Style = European | American deriving (Eq, Show)

call :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
call = undefined

put :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
put = undefined

price :: Option -> Double -> Double -> Double
price ( Option ( Future s ) Call European k t ) r v = call s k r t v
price ( Option ( Future s ) Put European k t ) r v = put s k r t v
price ( Option ( Forward s ) Call European k t ) r v = call s k r t v
price ( Option ( Forward s ) Put European k t ) r v = put s k r t v
```

So I've combined the `Forward` and `Future` types into a single type. This then avoids the need to make `Option` a higher kinded type. The type class can then be removed, and `price` can be defined with simple pattern matching.